# Listar várias ul dentro de uma li usando AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Como eu posso listar varios `ul` dentro de uma `li`, dinamicamente, com AJAX?

Algo como `ul>li>ul>li>ul>li`

A dúvida surgiu pois estou fazendo uma rede linear de um sistema de MMN e não consigo carregar dinamicamente a `ul` após a primeira `li`.

Comment: Tem de explicar melhor o que pretende faze e qual o resultado que quer. Bem como algum código que tenha tentado.

Comment: o resultado que eu gostaria seria igual a esse: https://www.dropbox.com/s/69zegxe72ko4kb8/Capturar.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Você consegue gerar seu conteúdo de lado servidor, ou utiliza dados de algum servidor fora do seu controle?

Comment: sim o sistema já está selecionando a tabela no db e enviando via json para o ajax eu quero ver como que faz para listar isso no html :S

Comment: Oi, Eduardo, em vez de adicionar informações aqui nos comentários, clique em [edit] e inclua esses detalhes na própria pergunta. Não editei eu mesmo porquê parece que a imagem tem detalhes de particulares; se puder faça um exemplo genérico.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, quer colocar dinamicamente um `<ul>` dentro de um `<li>` retornado por AJAX e se bem entendi quer fazê-lo com JQUERY. Coloco aqui um exemplo que responde ao que entendi na pergunta.

html:

```
<ul id="teste">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

No JQUERY:

```
$("ul#teste li").each(function () {
    var retorno_ajax = "<ul><li>sub-linha1</li><li>sub-linha2</li></ul>";
    $(this).html(retorno_ajax);
});
```

O `each` acede ao conteúdo dinâmico também. Não esquecer que o `.html` irá eliminar o conteúdo anterior e colocar o novo que para o exemplo resulta. No entanto se pretender adicionar o retorno ao conteúdo existente dentro da `li`então utilize o `append`.